Lipschitz Vector field which acts positively on the gradient
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz function. Let $U_\delta=\{|f|<\delta\}$ be open. I want to show that given any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that there is a Lipschitz vector field $X:U_\delta\to \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $X(x)\cdot \nabla f(x)>\epsilon$ for every $x\in U_\delta$.
Now I want to consider the outward normal vector field of $U_\delta$. Then that satisfies $X\cdot \nabla f>0$. So now can we choose $\delta>0$ such that this is bigger than $\epsilon$? There's another issue here that $U_\delta$ isn't a smooth submanifold with boundary, but it is open, and how can I define outward vector field for any open submanifold? I would be thankful if anyone can help or give me hints.
